# Webpack cannot find sass-loader provided by @rails/webpacker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, sass, webpacker

When I try to import an scss file in my Vue component:

```js
import './my_scss_file.scss';
```

I get an error that says:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'sass-loader'
// ...
[/home/app/node_modules]
[/home/node_modules]
[/node_modules]
[/home/app/web/node_modules/sass-loader]
[/home/app/web/node_modules/sass-loader.js]
[/home/app/web/node_modules/sass-loader.json]
```

As shown above, webpack tries to find `sass-loader` directly in `node_modules`. However, I found that my `sass-loader` module actually lives elsewhere:

```
/home/app/web/node_modules/@rails/webpacker/node_modules/sass-loader
```

How can I indicate to webpack where to find this `sass-loader`?

I'm on Rails 6.1, webpacker 4.3.0, webpack 4.41.2.

I tried adding a resolve alias to my `environment.js` to no avail:

```js
sass_loader = {
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'sass-loader': '@rails/webpacker/node_modules/sass-loader'
    }
  }
};
environment.config.merge(sass_loader);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use a library directly - it's better to have a direct dependency on it and not rely on some other library to add a dependency (which it may cease to do in the future)

Add `sass-loader` to your `package.json` via `yarn add sass-loader` (or manually and then run `yarn install`) and you'll have it in node_modules

Comment: Note that Yarn use wasn't specified, so use `npm install sass-loader` if still using Node's default package manager

Comment: rails webpacker is set up with yarn by default, but for completeness' sake you're correct

Answer (score 0):

try changing resolve.alias to resolve.modules

```
const sass_loader = {
  resolve: {
    modules: [
      'node_modules/@rails/webpacker/node_modules',
    ],
  },
};
environment.config.merge(sass_loader);
```

Then restart your development server.

Comment: @Mat - I think this worked for you since you awarded the bounty, please select this as "the answer" so that it helps others and comes above in the search results